# C++ code to Flowchart & Psudocode

Tags: c++, flowchart

I am looking for a tool can convert C++ code to Flow chart & Psudocode, can I find one ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can use crystal_FLOW

http://www.sgvsarc.com/Prods/CFLOW/Crystal_FLOW.htm

Comment: Is it useful for Psudocode also?

Comment: No but it will help you to understanding code easily by providing Comment-based flowcharts

Comment: @Aan For completeness, our tool Code Rocket (http://www.rapidqualitysystems.com) does pseudocode and flowcharts.